# Questions about lines on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

In Beauville's *Complex Algebraic Surfaces*, there were some claims about lines on a surface which appeared in proofs, but I can't seem to find justifications for them, and I hope to get some help here.

In the proof of Proposition IV.12, for a del Pezzo surface $S_d$, it's written that

> Since $H \equiv -K$, the lines on $S_d$ are just its exceptional curves.

1. Is $H$ an arbitrary hyperplane here? How does *every line is an exceptional curve* follow from $H \equiv -K$?

Also, in the second line of Proposition IV.16, where $S$ is the complete intersection of two quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$, the second line of the proof writes:

> Any line $E \subset S$ satisfies $E.H=1$, so $E.K = -1$ and $E^2 = -1$.

2. How do all these follow from the description of $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the degree-genus formula: If $ C $ is a smooth curve of geometric genus $ g $ on a surface $ S $ (this can be relaxed to arithmetic genus too, for singular curves, by a deformation argument) then $ 2g -2 = C \cdot (C + K_S) $

In your case if $ C $ is a line $ L $, then $ g=0 $ and $ L.H = 1 $ for a **general** hyperplane, or rather hyperplane section of $ S $. Since $ K_S = -H $ the formula reads $ -2 = L^2 - 1 $ so $ L^2 = -1 $ showing $ L $ is exceptional.

Comment: The first claim is often (usually?) known as the adjunction formula - those wishing to learn more about that claim may find the terminology helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when we speak of a line, do we always suppose it is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$? Or is that in the definition?

Comment: @KelvinLian I'm not sure I understand your question. A $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ being a line is a property of the embedding - more precisely it depends how you map your $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ into ambient projective space. For a line it should be by sections of $ O(1) $.

Comment: I'm sure you know of the twisted cubic. This is a rational curve, but this is NOT a line in $ \mathbb{P}^3 $ as the embedding is given by sections of $ O(3) $.

Comment: What I meant was, you said *since $L$ is a line, then $g=0$*, so I thought it meant that $L$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$. If you don't mind, could you explain a little what you meant by *for a line it should be done by sections of $\mathcal{O}(1)$*? I know by Hartshorne II.7.1 that an invertible sheaf on a variety corresponds to an embedding into some $\mathbb{P}^n$ and vice versa.

Comment: Yes. Maybe this is a better way to start thinking - A line in $ \mathbb{P}^n $ is given by the set of points $ \lambda [a] + \mu [b] $ for some two points $ [a] $ and $ [b] $. If you look at the section $ x_0 $ of $ O(1) $ on $ \mathbb{P}^n $, and restrict it to your line, what does it become? Answer: $ \lambda a_0 + \mu b_0 $, a section of $ O(1) $ on $ \mathbb{P}^1 $. This is what I meant when I said "for a line, the embedding has to be by sections of O(1)". Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Also, your last statement is not fully correct. An invertible sheaf **along with a generating set** of sections gives a map to projective space and this **may not be an embedding** (think of constant maps, obviously). See a later proposition of Hartshorne, 7.7. iirc, the keyword is to separate points and separate tangent vectors to have an embedding.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, they were really helpful towards my learning. Actually, I'm curious about the *general* hyperplane $H$. In what sense is it general? If I were to pick another hyperplane $H'$, how are $H$ and $H'$ related?

Comment: You're welcome. If you happen to pick the hyperplane so that the line lies entirely inside it, the intersection wouldn't be a single point, would it. So 'general' here means that the hyperplane is picked from the complement of the closed set of hyperplanes in the appropriate Grassmanian (here it's just the dual projective space) consisting of those which contain the line.